# Jenkins - Email notifications

Tags: notifications, jenkins

I'm trying to customize email using Groovy with the email-ext plugin. As I add new features to these emails, I may introduce errors in the scripts and so receive bad mails containing the StackTrace. So, I'd like to be able to send notifications on finished jobs as my jobs may take many hours (more than 4 currently).
Is there a way to ask jenkins to send notifications on finished jobs (using Groovy or any other scripting language)?

Comment: The Email-ext plugin allows you to use a different templates (with jelly script) depending on the outcome of the Build. You can config the plugin to send a different mail if the build fails, if it succeeds and on some other occasions... Isn't this what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi, I've already configure those triggers but my need is to add new features to the emails linked to those triggers and so I'd like to be able to send those notifications on passed jobs.

Comment: Do you mean the trigger functionality in [email-ext][1] plugin ?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321649/gitweb-how-to-display-markdown-file-in-html-format-automatically-like-github

Answer (score 0):

find a solution :

```py
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import groovy.text.Template
import groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine
import javax.mail.*
import javax.mail.internet.*

//-------------- Job params --------------
projectName="YourProjectName";
buildNum = 10;
templateName="groovy-html-cobertura.template";
recipients="someone@somewhere.com";
sender="jenkins@somewhere.com";
smtpHost="mysmtphost";
//------------End Job params -------------

for (hudson.model.AbstractProject p : hudson.model.Hudson.instance.projects) {
  if(p.name.equals(projectName)){
    for (hudson.model.AbstractBuild b : p.getBuilds() ) {
      if(b.getNumber() == buildNum){
        println b;
        b.reload();
        def binding = [ "build" : b, 
                        "project" : b.getProject(),
                        "rooturl" : hudson.model.Hudson.getInstance().getRootUrl(),
                        "it" : new     hudson.plugins.emailext.plugins.content.ScriptContentBuildWrapper(b),
                        "spc" : "&nbsp;&nbsp;" ]
        def engine = new SimpleTemplateEngine()
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File(hudson.model.Hudson.getInstance   ().getRootPath().getBaseName()+"/email-templates/"+templateName);
        mailBody = engine.createTemplate(file.getText()).make(binding).toString();
        port = 25
        props = new Properties()
        props.put('mail.smtp.host', smtpHost)
        props.put('mail.smtp.port', port.toString())
        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null)

        // Construct the message
        msg = new MimeMessage(session)
        msg.from = new InternetAddress(sender)
        msg.sentDate = new Date()
        msg.subject = 'Template Test'
        msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients))
        msg.setHeader('Organization', 'i-BP')
        msg.setContent(mailBody,
                   'text/html')
        // Send the message
        Transport.send(msg)
      }
    }
  }
}
```