# Gitweb: how to display markdown file in html format automatically like github

Tags: perl, markdown, gitweb

Markdown is important for documentation, it is very nice to see `README.md` can be automatically show in html format in github like https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/README.md

gitweb is written in perl script, and there is plugin for markdown in perl already.

I want to check whether there is plugin/solution to let gitweb automatically show html files for markdown format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's something you can stick somewhere under `sub git_summary` in your `gitweb.perl` or `gitweb.cgi`. Note that it depends on an external `markdown` executable.

```
if (!$prevent_xss) {
    $file_name = "README.md";
    my $proj_head_hash = git_get_head_hash($project);
    my $readme_blob_hash = git_get_hash_by_path($proj_head_hash, "README.md", "blob");

    if ($readme_blob_hash) { # if README.md exists                                                                                                                                                      
        print "<div class=\"header\">readme</div>\n";
        print "<div class=\"readme page_body\">"; # TODO find/create a better CSS class than page_body                                                                                                  

        my $cmd_markdownify = $GIT . " " . git_cmd() . " cat-file blob " . $readme_blob_hash . " | markdown |";
        open FOO, $cmd_markdownify or die_error(500, "Open git-cat-file blob '$hash' failed");
        while (<FOO>) {
            print $_;
        }
        close(FOO);

        print "</div>";
    }
}
```

I don't really know Perl, so this is a dirty hack more than anything else, but it works.

Comment: Hello, seems to work despite two small issues : if your README.md file contains code that use tag (xml, html, ...) it must be xhtml strict valid. You should write `<link ... />` not `<link ...>`. The second issue, is more likely a conversion issue. All files/servers are in UTF-8 but after markdown conversion I got bad encoding characters _Ce module, codÃ© en AngularJS Ã_

Comment: I changed the line `print $_;` to `print to_utf8($_);` -- works for me :-)

Answer (score 14):

I use following post-receive hook in my remote repositories which are made browsable with gitweb.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Post-receive hook script which generates README.html to git-dir from
# README.md found at the head of master branch in repository.
#
# Gitweb can read the README.html and embed it to the project summary page.

git cat-file blob HEAD:README.md | markdown > $GIT_DIR/README.html
```

That script is run when I push commits from my local work repositories to the remote bare ones. You could use that or something similar depending on your workflow/setup.

More information about git hooks: http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html

Comment: $GIT_DIR is automatically set when the hook is executed.

Answer (score 4):

Here are my modifications to `gitweb.cgi` based on the accepted answer, so that:

- `README.md` in the project root is displayed (as in accepted answer)
- Any `*.md` file is displayed if it is chosen as file from the tree view
- local links among .md files in a project are preserved (i.e. `(my parent)[../parent.md]` would refer correctly); should work for images as well

Note that I'm using `sudo apt-get install libtext-markdown-perl` on Ubuntu to provide the required `markdown` executable.

Here are the modifications as a `diff` patch:

```
--- /usr/share/gitweb/gitweb.cgi.orig   2016-04-13 10:28:03.268872899 +0200
+++ /usr/share/gitweb/gitweb.cgi    2016-04-13 10:39:02.344875516 +0200
@@ -16,8 +16,9 @@
 use Encode;
 use Fcntl ':mode';
 use File::Find qw();
-use File::Basename qw(basename);
+use File::Basename qw(basename dirname);
 use Time::HiRes qw(gettimeofday tv_interval);
+use File::Spec; # hack
 binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';

 our $t0 = [ gettimeofday() ];
@@ -6585,6 +6586,20 @@
        print "\n</div>\n"; # class="readme"
    }

+   # hack
+   if (!$prevent_xss) {
+       $file_name = "README.md";
+       my $proj_head_hash = git_get_head_hash($project);
+       my $readme_blob_hash = git_get_hash_by_path($proj_head_hash, "README.md", "blob");
+
+       if ($readme_blob_hash) { # if README.md exists
+           print "<div class=\"header\">$file_name</div>\n";
+           print "<div class=\"readme page_body\">"; # TODO find/create a better CSS class than page_body
+           print get_markdown($file_name, $readme_blob_hash);
+           print "</div>";
+       }
+   }
+
    # we need to request one more than 16 (0..15) to check if
    # those 16 are all
    my @commitlist = $head ? parse_commits($head, 17) : ();
@@ -7059,6 +7074,9 @@
    $fd = run_highlighter($fd, $highlight, $syntax)
        if $syntax;

+   # hack
+   my $ismarkdown = ($file_name =~ /md$/);
+
    git_header_html(undef, $expires);
    my $formats_nav = '';
    if (defined $hash_base && (my %co = parse_commit($hash_base))) {
@@ -7102,6 +7120,10 @@
              href(action=>"blob_plain", hash=>$hash,
                   hash_base=>$hash_base, file_name=>$file_name) .
              qq!" />\n!;
+   } elsif ($ismarkdown) {
+       print qq!<div class="readme page_body">\n!;
+       print get_markdown($file_name, $hash);
+       print qq!</div>\n!; #  $cmd_markdownify
    } else {
        my $nr;
        while (my $line = <$fd>) {
@@ -7119,6 +7141,79 @@
    git_footer_html();
 }

+# hack
+sub get_norm_rel_path { # http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=11907
+   my $unnormpath = shift;
+   while ($unnormpath =~ m!/\.!) {
+       $unnormpath =~ s!/[^\/]+/\.\.!!;
+       # print "Path is now -+$unnormpath+-\n";
+   }
+   return $unnormpath;
+}
+sub get_markdown {
+   my $tfilename = shift;
+   my $thash = shift;
+   my $rethtmlstr = "";
+   use open ":encoding(utf8)"; # needed to have utf8 survive through the shell pipe
+   my $cmd_markdownify = $GIT . " " . git_cmd() . " cat-file blob " . $thash . " | perl -e 'my \$str = do { local \$/; <STDIN> }; \$str =~ s/<!--.*?--\s*>//gs; print \$str;' | markdown |";
+   open (FOO, $cmd_markdownify) or die_error(500, "Open git-cat-file blob '$thash' failed");
+   while (<FOO>) {
+       if ($_ =~ /(<img[^>]src=")(.*?)"/) {
+           my $origcut = "".$2;
+           my $testcut = "".$2;
+           my $is_anchor = ($testcut =~ /^#/);
+           my $is_absolute = ($testcut =~ /^http/);
+           my $is_relative_up = ($testcut =~ /^\.\./);
+           my $is_local_link = ((!$is_anchor) and (!$is_absolute));
+           my $tdir = dirname($tfilename);
+           my $is_tdir_proper = (($tdir ne "") and ($tdir ne "."));
+           #print "XX: $origcut ($is_anchor, $is_absolute - $is_local_link) ($is_relative_up, $is_tdir_proper, $tdir, $tfilename)\n"; # dbg
+           if ($is_local_link) {
+               if ($is_relative_up) { # normalize
+                   if ($is_tdir_proper) {
+                       # cheat with absolute path here:
+                       my $resolved = get_norm_rel_path( File::Spec->rel2abs ("$origcut", "/$tdir" ) );
+                       $resolved = substr $resolved, 1;
+                       #print "YY: $resolved\n";
+                       $_ =~ s!(<img[^>]src=")(.*?)"!$1?p=$project;a=blob_plain;f=$resolved"!gi;
+                   }
+               } else {
+                   $_ =~ s!(<img[^>]src=")(.*?)"!$1?p=$project;a=blob_plain;f=$2"!gi;
+                   #print "ZZ: $_\n";
+               }
+           }
+       }
+       if ($_ =~ /(<a[^>]href=")(.*?)"/) {
+           my $origcut = "".$2;
+           my $testcut = "".$2;
+           my $is_anchor = ($testcut =~ /^#/);
+           my $is_absolute = ($testcut =~ /^http/);
+           my $is_relative_up = ($testcut =~ /^\.\./);
+           my $is_local_link = ((!$is_anchor) and (!$is_absolute));
+           my $tdir = dirname($tfilename);
+           my $is_tdir_proper = (($tdir ne "") and ($tdir ne "."));
+           #print "XX: $origcut ($is_anchor, $is_absolute - $is_local_link) ($is_relative_up, $is_tdir_proper, $tdir, $tfilename)\n"; # dbg
+           if ($is_local_link) {
+               if ($is_relative_up) { # normalize
+                   if ($is_tdir_proper) {
+                       # cheat with absolute path here:
+                       my $resolved = get_norm_rel_path( File::Spec->rel2abs ("$origcut", "/$tdir" ) );
+                       $resolved = substr $resolved, 1;
+                       #print "YY: $resolved\n";
+                       $_ =~ s!(<a[^>]href=")(.*?)"!$1?p=$project;a=blob;f=$resolved"!gi;
+                   }
+               } else {
+                   $_ =~ s!(<a[^>]href=")(.*?)"!$1?p=$project;a=blob;f=$2"!gi;
+                   #print "ZZ: $_\n";
+               }
+           }
+       }
+       $rethtmlstr .= $_;
+   }
+   close(FOO);
+   return $rethtmlstr;
+}
+
 sub git_tree {
    if (!defined $hash_base) {
        $hash_base = "HEAD";
```

Comment: Reformatted to match its tab-whitespacing: https://www.jankratochvil.net/t/markdown.patch

Comment: I had to adjust the patch to get it to apply to gitweb 2.26 (taken from Alpine Linux package). My update gist [here](https://gist.github.com/johnlane/b0eb78dc97694d3a42d8dedcc6a5d095).

Answer (score 0):

I use this tampermonkey script in chrome to render README.md files as html, directly in gitweb:
https://gist.github.com/nemoo/ee47cd9ad2a5b4fdddfa  Works nicely even if you do not have access to the gitweb server.